# CFileDialog's DoModal fills debug window

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

```
CStringW strFilter;
strFilter.LoadStringW(IDS_IMGFILEFILTER);
//Image Files (*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg;*.png;*.tif)*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg;*.png;*.tif|All Files (*.*)|*.*||

CFileDialog dlgFile(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT |
    OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, strFilter, AfxGetMainWnd());
if (dlgFile.DoModal() != IDOK) return;
```

Using Windows 10, 64bit

Errors appear immediately after DoModal called, before any interaction with dialog.

Output window:

> ```
> mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2125)\OLEAUT32.dll!00007FF9F66E2CA6: (caller: 00007FF9F66E2DCA) ReturnHr(1) tid(2cac) 8002801D Library not registered.
> The thread 0x27b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9F503A388 (KernelBase.dll) in ProgramName.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.
> onecoreuap\shell\windows.storage\homefolder.cpp(506)\windows.storage.dll!00007FF9F48A2884: (caller: 00007FF9F47CB563) ReturnHr(1) tid(3b00) 80070490 Element not found.
> onecoreuap\shell\windows.storage\regfldr.cpp(1242)\windows.storage.dll!00007FF9F489F30D: (caller: 00007FF9F47C83E8) ReturnHr(2) tid(3b00) 80070490 Element not found.
> onecoreuap\shell\windows.storage\homefolder.cpp(506)\windows.storage.dll!00007FF9F48A2884: (caller: 00007FF9F47CB563) ReturnHr(3) tid(3b00) 80070490 Element not found.
> onecoreuap\shell\windows.storage\regfldr.cpp(1242)\windows.storage.dll!00007FF9F489F30D: (caller: 00007FF9F47C83E8) ReturnHr(4) tid(3b00) 80070490 Element not found.
> onecoreuap\shell\windows.storage\homefolder.cpp(506)\windows.storage.dll!00007FF9F48A2884: (caller: 00007FF9F47CB563) ReturnHr(5) tid(2cac) 80070490 Element not found.
> onecoreuap\shell\windows.storage\regfldr.cpp(1242)\windows.storage.dll!00007FF9F489F30D: (caller: 00007FF9F47C83E8) ReturnHr(6) tid(2cac) 80070490 Element not found.
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(676)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3824: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA3604) ReturnHr(1) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(758)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3653: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA34DE) LogHr(1) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> Msg:[Creating icon overlay handler from 敒楧瑳祲 failed. The CLSID is {BBACC218-34EA-4666-9D7A-C78F2274A524}.] 
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(676)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3824: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA3604) ReturnHr(2) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(758)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3653: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA34DE) LogHr(2) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> Msg:[Creating icon overlay handler from 敒楧瑳祲 failed. The CLSID is {5AB7172C-9C11-405C-8DD5-AF20F3606282}.] 
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(676)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3824: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA3604) ReturnHr(3) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(758)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3653: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA34DE) LogHr(3) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> Msg:[Creating icon overlay handler from 敒楧瑳祲 failed. The CLSID is {A78ED123-AB77-406B-9962-2A5D9D2F7F30}.] 
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(676)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3824: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA3604) ReturnHr(4) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(758)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3653: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA34DE) LogHr(4) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> Msg:[Creating icon overlay handler from 敒楧瑳祲 failed. The CLSID is {F241C880-6982-4CE5-8CF7-7085BA96DA5A}.] 
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(676)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3824: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA3604) ReturnHr(5) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(758)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3653: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA34DE) LogHr(5) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> Msg:[Creating icon overlay handler from 敒楧瑳祲 failed. The CLSID is {A0396A93-DC06-4AEF-BEE9-95FFCCAEF20E}.] 
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(676)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3824: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA3604) ReturnHr(6) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(758)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3653: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA34DE) LogHr(6) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> Msg:[Creating icon overlay handler from 敒楧瑳祲 failed. The CLSID is {9AA2F32D-362A-42D9-9328-24A483E2CCC3}.] 
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(676)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3824: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA3604) ReturnHr(7) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> shell\shell32\ovrlaymn.cpp(758)\SHELL32.dll!00007FF9F6BA3653: (caller: 00007FF9F6BA34DE) LogHr(7) tid(2f64) 80040154 Class not registered
> Msg:[Creating icon overlay handler from 敒楧瑳祲 failed. The CLSID is {C5FF006E-2AE9-408C-B85B-2DFDD5449D9C}.]
> ```

But, don't see any problems with program execuation.

Also tried bVistaStyle = FALSE and copied the file name buffer code as shown here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=vs-2017

Still a page full of error messages.

File sharing has been intentionally disabled. Possible reason for "The RPC server is unavailable"?

Have seen the "OLEAUT32.dll Library not registered" message before in the default
frame work VS created for a win32 desktop application but, message there went away several
updates ago. Never caused any problems.

Know nothing about "windows.storage" but seems to provide access to known folders
like "Desktop", "Documents" and others. No problems accessing these folders.

My biggest concern is that those Chinese (or whatever foreign language that is)
processes definitely look like there is some kind of corruption.

Creating my own file name buffer seems unecessary as it works perfectly without it
and "GetStartPosition" and "GetNextPathName" are bypassed in microsoft's example.
Has this been updated?

Comment: this is internal win 10 output. unrelated to your code. simply ignore this

Comment: I don't see `Msg:[Creating icon overlay handler from 敒楧瑳祲 ...` in my VS2017/Win10 environment. Maybe that's another process which is printing debug messages incorrectly. It shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Any way to filter out these messages.
This clutter makes it harder to debug.
Enabled "Just My Code" in debug options but, it didn't do anything.
Couldn't find any other options that seemed applicable.

Comment: The CLSIDs mentioned in the logs belong to Microsoft OneDrive.  Since it mentions that the "Class not registered",  it appears that OneDrive's installation is broken.  (Registration as icon handler exists, but DLL is not registered.)  In this case, the file dialog is trying to initialize shell extensions and failing.  This is not a problem with your code.  The reason for the RPC error is unclear. Do you have the debugger set to stop on exceptions?

Comment: I uninstalled (or thought I uninstalled) OneDrive. Apparently not completely. Re-installed then, uninstalled it again. Didn't help. Lots of stuff on internet about registry entries. Hoped I wouldn't have to do that (there's a lot of them). May just have to live with the beast. Debugger only breaks at unhandled exceptions.